# Copying a row from one mysql table to another table, and modifying field values

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table`daily` and a table`food`. In `food`, I store a database of foods I eat into `food`. In `daily`, I only store foods I eat for the day (must be selected from `food`, modified, and stored in `daily`), and at the end of the day, the `daily` table is purged (all rows dropped with `DELETE FROM daily`).

What I'm trying to figure out is how I can copy one row from table `food` and copy it to table `daily` while modifying it's values.

Both `food` and `daily` have an identical structure.

**food** (nothing in this table ever changes)

```
name    calories   grams  fat   protein
---------------------------------------
apple   50         80     1.2   2
potato  90         45     3.4   5
carrot  10         70     6.2   6
```

**daily** (the table after I ate an apple that is 93g as per example)

```
name    calories   grams  fat   protein
---------------------------------------
apple   58.125     93     1.395 2.325
```

**example**

I weigh out a food that only exists in my food database, and if it doesn't, I'll have to add it in.

I then pick a food from a dropdown and enter it's weight in grams.

I choose from the list an `apple`. I weigh my `apple` and it is `93g`.

My `93g` is divided by `80g` which yields `1.1625`. All the stats for the `apple` (fat and protein) have to be multiplied by `1.1625` and then inserted into my `daily` table.

How can I retrieve a row from `food`, modify every value in it by my modifier (`1.1625`), and insert it into my `daily` table?

---

I just realized that I can load up whichever food I select into an array and modify each cells values, then pump that array into `daily`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP you would just load the row, modify the values and build a query to insert it into `daily`. Nothing fancy there, so I guess you are asking about how to do it in SQL:

```
INSERT INTO daily (name,
                   calories,
                   grams,
                   fat,
                   protein)
SELECT name,
       calories * 1.1625,
       grams * 1.1625,
       fat * 1.1625,
       protein * 1.1625
FROM food
WHERE name = "apple"
```

Comment: UPDATE TABLE daily set calories=(calories*1.1625) ,grams=(grams*1.625),fat=fat*1.625....will this not work ?

Comment: As I understood the question, in the beginning there is no row in `daily` to update, it has to come from `food`.

Comment: All foods in `daily` are modified from `foods` as I can't add a daily food unless it's in my central food database.

Answer (score 2):

Can I suggest a slight modification to your schema that might make your life simpler? With the one you have, your data is not normalized.

Change your daily table to contain only two columns, one for the name and one for the grams, and this is the only information you need to insert, no need to modify any values from the food table.

Now, to retrieve the values you want to display daily, do this:

```
SELECT d.name, d.grams, f.fat*(d.grams/f.grams), f.protein*(d.grams/f.grams) 
FROM daily d, food f
WHERE f.name=d.name;
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Cool, yeah that works. My database is a bit more complicated, I have 16 fields total (for all values on a nutrition label).